# postgreSQL Pivoting like query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, postgresql, pivot

Let me explain my situation, I have a table example in excel and is like this, TOTAL column doesn't matter for now.

```
    Nombre      MachID  LUN-25  TOTAL   MART-26 TOTAL   MIER-27 TOTAL
1   LUPITA      1       100     <blank> <blank> <blank> 20      <blank>
2   LUPITA      2       150     <blank> <blank> <blank> 30      <blank>
3   LUPITA      3       200     450     <blank> <blank> 50      100
4   SELENE      4       148     380     256     256     <blank> <blank>
5   SERGIO BILL 5       509     370     500     500     <blank> <blank>
```

And i am doing some query joining tables and Pivot them, but I get some table like this.

```
    Nombre      MachID  LUN-25  TOTAL   MART-26 TOTAL   MIER-27 TOTAL
1   LUPITA      1       100     <blank> <blank> <blank> <blank> <blank>
2   LUPITA      2       150     <blank> <blank> <blank> <blank> <blank>
3   LUPITA      3       200     450     <blank> <blank> <blank> 
4   LUPITA      1       <blank> <blank> <blank> <blank> 20      <blank>
5   LUPITA      2       <blank> <blank> <blank> <blank> 30      <blank>
6   LUPITA      3       <blank> <blank> <blank> <blank> 50      100
7   SELENE      4       148     380     <blank> <blank> <blank> <blank>
8   SELENE      4       <blank> <blank> 256     256     <blank> <blank>
9   SERGIO BILL 5       509     370     <blank> <blank> <blank> <blank>
10  SERGIO BILL 5       <blank> <blank> 500     500     <blank> <blank>
```

this is my query

```
    select 
    u.nombre, 
    m.codigo_barras::text as "id_maquina", 
    (select v1.entrada  from tb_visita v1 where date_trunc('day',v1.fecha_visita) =  '2017-06-08 05:37:43.559'::date - integer '6' and v1.id_visita = v.id_visita) as "vie. 2 de junio", 
    (select v1.entrada  from tb_visita v1 where date_trunc('day',v1.fecha_visita) =  '2017-06-08 05:37:43.559'::date - integer '5' and v1.id_visita = v.id_visita) as "sáb. 3 de junio", 
    (select v1.entrada  from tb_visita v1 where date_trunc('day',v1.fecha_visita) =  '2017-06-08 05:37:43.559'::date - integer '4' and v1.id_visita = v.id_visita) as "dom. 4 de junio", 
    from tb_visita v 
    INNER JOIN tb_maquinas m ON m.id_maquina = v.id_maquina 
    inner join tb_usuarios u on u.id = v.id_usuario 
    where date_trunc('day',v.fecha_visita) >=  '2017-06-08 05:37:43.559'::date - integer '6' and date_trunc('day',v.fecha_visita) <=  '2017-06-08 05:37:43.559'::date 

    order by u.nombre ASC, t.nombre_contacto ASC ;
```

As you can see, my detail is that there are repetitive rows that can be grouped in the same row as they are for different day, actually i am reading [this](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78), i will see if that can clear my mind and help me to solve this.

I don't think it is necessary to put the table structure, but I'll update if needed.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: PostgreSQL, always thought they were the same.

Comment: The basics are the same, but there are also lots of differences (e.g. `date_trunc` and `::`.)